# How to get a value on a 3rd column in dataframe depending on the difference between the first and second columns?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a table as follows:

start   end
5       5
4       8
10      19
4       4

Now what I want to do is, if the value on the two columns in a particular row is equal, then print only one of them in the 3rd column. If they are different, then print - start + "-" + end. The data is in a dataframe. Example is this:

start    end    range
5        5      5
4        8      4-8
10       19     10-19
4        4      4

This is the code I am trying:

```
if df['start'] - df['end'] != 0:
   df['range'] = df['start'] + "-" + df['end']
else:
   df['range'] = df['start']
```

But this is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['range'] = np.where(df['start'] != df['end'], df['start'] + "-" + df['end'], df['start'])
```

Similar another solution:

```
df['range'] = df['start'] + np.where(df['start'] != df['end'], "-" + df['end'], '')

print (df)
  start end  range
0     5   5      5
1     4   8    4-8
2    10  19  10-19
3     4   4      4
```

Solution if values are not strings:

```
s = df['start'].astype(str) 
e = df['end'].astype(str)

df['range'] = np.where(df['start'] != df['end'], s + "-" + e, s)
```

Similar another solution:

```
df['range'] = s + np.where(df['start'] != df['end'], "-" + e, '')
```

Comment: Why have you assigned twice?

Comment: @SayantanGhosh - It is 2 solution, choose what you like more ;)